# Ошибка "No drawer view found with gravity LEFT"

Tags: android, drawerlayout, androidx

**Разметка:**

```xml
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/HonorsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutToolBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageMenu1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_book"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitle12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/monserat"
                android:text="@string/Honor"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Активити:**

```java
public class HonorsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_honors);
        final DrawerLayout HonorsActivity = findViewById(R.id.HonorsActivity);
        findViewById(R.id.imageMenu1).setOnClickListener(v -> HonorsActivity.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));
    }

}
```

**Logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm, PID: 21217
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1790)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1776)
    at com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm.HonorsActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(HonorsActivity.java:18)
    at com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm.HonorsActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2023-03-14 22:12:32.134  1638-2233  ActivityManager system_server E  Found activity ActivityRecord{2a2ab7b u0 com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm/.MainActivity t-1 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{8296299 21217:com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm/u0a85}
2023-03-14 22:12:32.202  1638-1698  InputDispatcher system_server E  channel '94e0b08 com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm/com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Ругается на openDrawer, в чем проблема?

Comment: Просьба отформатировать код (вы же не в блокноте пишете код?). Постарайтесь сфокусировать ваш вопрос на одной проблеме. Сейчас в вашем вопросе сразу несколько проблем. Как минимум я вижу здесь две проблемы: 1) Крэш с ошибкой и стектрейсом, 2) "нужно сделать переход назад"

Comment: Ознакомтесь, [как создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), чтобы убрать из вопроса весь лишний код и сосредоточить ваш вопрос только на конкретной проблеме. Например, я думаю, что `ArrayAdapter` к проблеме отношения не имеет, зачем он тогда в вопросе?

Comment: Мне пришлось откатить ваши последние изменения, так как, на мой взгляд, вы попытались уместить несколько вопросов в один. При этом вы использовали код, который вы взяли из уже написанного мной ответа. Так лучше не делать, а лучше завести отдельный вопрос.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`DrawerLayout` [требует](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout), чтобы внутри него находилась вьюха с выставленным `layout_gravity`.

Так как у вас внутри `DrawerLayout` нет подходящей вью с `layout_gravity`, то вы получаете эту ошибку:

> No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Чтобы ее исправить, добавьте, например, `FrameLayout` внутрь вашего `DrawerLayout`, в котором будет атрибут `layout_gravity=start`:

```xml
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout ... >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >
        
        <!-- контент, который будет выдвигаться слева -->
        
    </FrameLayout>

    ...

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

В этот `FrameLayout` поместите контент, который будет выдвигаться при нажатии на кнопку.

Теперь, при вызове `openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)` ошибки не будет, контент будет выдвигаться слева при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: где находится тулбар нужно фраймелаяут ?

Comment: поменял, выдает эту ошибку HonorsActivity <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>: No speakable text present

Comment: щас поправлю и попробую изложится более конкретно

Comment: отредачил, тогда весь бар на всю страницу, либо Я туплю, либо лыжи не едут( и так же назад не переходит

Comment: Сфокусируйтесь на одной проблеме, у вас была конкретная ошибка — мой ответ ее исправляет? Сейчас вы выложили код, в котором, вероятно, новые проблемы. Если у вас есть новый вопрос, то лучше заведите его отдельно и приложите полный стектрейс ошибки. Сейчас не совсем ясно, какую проблему решаем.

Comment: всю туже) нужен переход назад)

Comment: сейчас ошибок нет, но этот "тулбар" на весь экран и не возращает назад, ошибок нет, и мне не нужно выдвигаться с лево, а нужно перейти назад, сейчас приложу скрины для более понятной картины

Comment: "нужен переход назад" -- код за вас здесь писать не будут. Если у вас есть конкретная проблема, с которой вы столкнулсь, решая вашу задачу, то опишите ее в новом вопросе. Сейчас вы выложили тонну кода, которая с исходной ошибкой совсем не связана.

Comment: Собственно проблема та остается по сути тажа, просто Вашим вариантом, в разметку Я сдвигаю все в "выпадающий список" или как его назвать, и в итоге у меня на экране получается это все , что на скрине, Я не прошу писать за меня код, хотя там по сути пару строчек будет ...

Comment: Изначальный заголовок вашего вопроса: "Ошибка при нажатии на кнопку назад в тулбаре". Изначальное тело вашего вопроса: "Ругается на openDrawer, в чем проблема?". И код. Я максимально точно ответил на этот вопрос, объяснил в ответе, с чем связана ваша ошибка. Если у вас новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, исходный вопрос не был задан так, как вы его сейчас хотите преподнести.

Comment: понял, спасибо.